# Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image. in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, gd, image-compression, gd2

[image]

I am trying to compress the image size in codeigniter with the help of GD2 Image compression Library but its showing me error

```
Your server must support the GD image library in order to determine the image properties.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.
```

But on my server It is showing GD enabled

```
array(12) { ["GD Version"]=> string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)" ["FreeType Support"]=> bool(true) ["FreeType Linkage"]=> string(13) "with freetype" ["GIF Read Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Create Support"]=> bool(true) ["JPEG Support"]=> bool(true) ["PNG Support"]=> bool(true) ["WBMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["XPM Support"]=> bool(true) ["XBM Support"]=> bool(true) ["WebP Support"]=> bool(true) ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=> bool(false) }
```

Here is my code

```
$file_path = './public/order_images/';
        if($_FILES['image_name']['name']!="")
        {
            $config['upload_path']          = $file_path;
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            // $config['max_size']             = 1000000;
            // print_r($config);exit;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image_name'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                // print_r($error);exit;
            }
            else
            {

                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $zfile = $data['upload_data']['full_path']; // get file path
                chmod($zfile,0777); // CHMOD file

                $img_config['image_library']          = 'gd2';
                $img_config['source_image']          = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
                $img_config['create_thumb']        = FALSE;
                $img_config['maintain_ratio']             = TRUE;
                $img_config['quality']             = '60%';
                $img_config['width']             = 150;
                $img_config['height']             = 75;
                $img_config['new_image']             = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/order_new_img/new_'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                // $this->resize($file_path,$data['upload_data']['file_name']);
                $size = filesize($data['upload_data']['full_path']);
                // pre($img_config);
                var_dump(gd_info());

                $this->load->library('image_lib');

                $this->image_lib->initialize($img_config);

                // $this->image_lib->resize();

                // pre(getimagesize($data['upload_data']['full_path']));
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()){

                        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();exit;

                    } else {

                        echo "done";exit;

                    }
                $this->image_lib->clear();
            }

            $image_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }
```

I also checked in php.info in that its also showing GD enabled but when I hit submit button this error showing

GD Not support

Please Help me to find the solution

Thank you in Advanced

Comment: is anyone is there ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you don't need the line `$this->upload->initialize($config);` because `initialize` ran when this call was made `$this->load->library('upload', $config);`

Comment: The first error happens in `image_lib::initialize` when PHP returns false to `function_exists('getimagesize').` But that makes no sense because `phpinfo()` clearly shows GD is enabled. There are newer versions of GD available maybe upgrading the server to a newer version of GD will help.

Comment: What I do know , Can you help me to solve this issue